# How to increase the Octets capacity in FreeRADIUS

Tags: attributes, 32bit-64bit, freeradius, radius

I am trying to increase the limits of "Acct-Input-Octets" and "Acct-Output-Octets" in freeRADIUS beyond 4,294,967,295, but I cannot. One of the reasons I come across is that in freRADIUS, those attributes use 32bits and I need 64bits to do that. I tried looking in the freeRADIUS files for a file defining those attributes but could not find any. Any suggestions?

> I am using FreeRADIUS 3.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Those attributes are 32 bit; the top 32 bits of the 64 bit value are in the `Acct-*-Gigawords` variants. You need to shift and add those two attributes together to get the full 64 bit value.

There is a policy in the default configuration to do this for you. See `raddb/accounting`. Uncomment

```
# acct_counters64
```

in your `preacct {}` section. This will create two internal attributes you can use, `&Acct-Input-Octets64` and `&Acct-Output-Octets64` which have the full 64 bit value.